# Filter Landsat 5 imagery in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-5

I am trying to understand some of surface reflectance values in Landsat 5 and how to deal with (what I think is) saturation. Here is an example. If I look at and image for 23 October 1984, everything looks okay:

```
var ROI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(24.68, 45.89,24.94,46.05);

function ScaleFactors_LS5_C2(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBand, null, true);
}

var cloudMask457_C2 = function(image) {
  var dilatedCloud = (1 << 1)
  var cloud = (1 << 3)
  var cloudShadow = (1 << 4)
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(dilatedCloud)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloud))
    .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadow))
  return image.updateMask(mask.not());
}


var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('1984-10-01', '1984-10-25')
    .filterBounds(ROI)
  .map(cloudMask457_C2)
  .map(ScaleFactors_LS5_C2)
  .first()
  .clip(ROI);
    
var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL')

var qaMask_params = {min: 0,max: 10}

var L457_C2params = {
  bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3
  }

Map.centerObject(image);
Map.addLayer(image, L457_C2params, 'True Color 3 2 1');
Map.addLayer(qaMask,qaMask_params);
```

However, if I change the dates to .filterDate('1984-04-01', '1984-04-29'), the resulting image looks like a mess, but the underlying QA_PIXEL values are the same for both images (5440). How does one either filter this image?

This is probably a very basic question, I just haven't ever encountered a lot of images like this. I have mainly worked with Landsat 5 after 1991.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the image metadata (by printing the image) that it's both not a very good image

```
IMAGE_QUALITY: 7
```

and that it's got saturation in most bands:

```
SATURATION_BAND_1: Y
SATURATION_BAND_2: Y
SATURATION_BAND_3: Y
SATURATION_BAND_4: Y
SATURATION_BAND_5: Y
SATURATION_BAND_6: N
SATURATION_BAND_7: Y
```

You can filter out such images with collection.filter(), e.g.:

```
ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
    .filter("IMAGE_QUALITY == 9")
    .filter("SATURATION_BAND_4 == 'N'")
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I am wondering if there is a way to generate a table from an image collection of the metadata. I am going to work on this and post as a new question if I can't figure it out.

Comment: You can simply cast the ImageCollection to a FeatureCollection and export it as a table.  ImageCollections are just specialized versions of FeatureCollections.